# downvote after hitting rep limit

Tags: support, status-bydesign, daily-reputation-limit

Let's suppose you exceed the reputation limit (you would have received 210 rep if the limit werent there) .  Then, before the next day, someone downvotes one of your responses.  Then your limits are:

```
BEFORE DOWNVOTE     200      (210 w/o limit)
AFTER DOWNVOTE      198      (208 w/o limit)
```

Shouldn't the rep be boosted to 200?

(In my case, yesterday I hit 243 (where I should have hit 245 -- I see partial points for an upvote, which suggests there are some points beyond the limit)

Comment: Yeh, it kinda sucks, one downvote at the end of the day, can kill your day for rep-cap badges.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that if this happens, you can send up a flag, and get your 2 rep back; I'm not sure where I read this from, unfortunately.

Comment: @LanceRoberts It seems like the most obvious thing would be to enforce the cap at the end of the day.  Very similar to some technicalities in my work :/

Comment: I also hate this. The order you get votes in the day shouldn't matter, but it does.

Comment: @NickCraver♦ can you explain the motivation behind this (if it is by design)?

Comment: Would you get the appropriate values if you trigger a recalc?

Comment: Consider also that the only "rep-cap badge" is Mortarboard, which is one day, and only awardable once, so it's not hard to get.  Epic and Legendary count days you got 200 rep or more, regardless of the cap.  So, for instance, a 245 cap, even when downvoted at the end of a day (resulting in 243), would still count toward Epic.

Answer (score 4):

That's by design as far as I can tell.

Technically, you don't actually *earn* the points above your reputation cap, so further downvotes cannot be compensated by these points.

However, that cuts both ways: if you're upvoted again before the next day, then an additional `+2` will be registered and compensate the previous downvote. And of course, if the downvoter cancels his vote, you'll also get your two points back.

Comment: I guess the question is: why isn't the reputation cap enforced at the end of the day?  It would seem to make the most sense that way ...

Comment: @Foo, reputation does not converge on midnight UTC, it seems to be kept as an ordered sequence of vote results. That can also lead to strange behavior [when you lose a lot of points while above the rep cap](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102000/164403), for instance :)