# Rep cap, downvotes and un-upvotes

Tags: discussion, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

I've read a comment from a user who's familiar with how reputation cap works on SE to an answer that received a lot of upvotes in a day saying they'll upvote it later so that it counts towards their rep.

So I thought: what would happen if a user posts a great answer, gets enough upvotes to reach daily rep cap and after that…

- Someone downvotes
- Someone un-upvotes

…reducing the answer poster's rep?

Will both of these cases lower daily rep gained and allow for more upvotes to count toward rep cap? Is it possible to get a ton of upvotes, reach daily rep cap and then lose more rep than gained due to un-upvotes? (also, can un-upvotes drain more rep than daily rep cap allows to gain?)

Comment: An upvote just cancels the upvote as if it was never cast; another upvote that didn't count against the cap would then count. A downvote does count, and another upvote would cover the difference up to the cap again.

Comment: [downvote after hitting rep limit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109027)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- An un-upvote cancels the previous vote, as if the upvote was never cast. If there was any later upvote that was subject to the cap, now *does* count.

  So if you received no downvotes and received 21 upvotes, then after an un-upvote you still gained 200 points from voting that day. If you received no downvotes and only 20 upvotes, the un-upvote leaves you with 190 points from votes.
- A downvote after reaching the rep cap still counts. You'll go down to 198 points from voting. Any upvote *after* the downvote will push you back up to the cap limit.

  So, if you reached the cap, got downvoted and received no further upvotes, you gained 198 points from voting that day. If you reached the cap, got downvoted then upvoted again, you gained 200 points from voting that day.

Comment: Theoretically, what if you'd receive enough upvotes to guarantee 500 rep (but you still got 200) and then on the next day or whenever that rep cap expires, everybody un-upvoted, would you lose 500 (or 300 or 100) rep or just the 200 you got due to rep cap at the time?

Comment: @user1306322: If everybody un-upvoted, you'd not have received upvotes and you lose 200 points. Un-upvoting just means: the vote never happened. So it'll be as if noone voted for you the previous day. It's not a +10 + -10 balance count.

Comment: I wonder if this still applies to the repcap calculations of the badges :D

Comment: The badge batch processes look at the “current” situation every time they run. That said, IIRC badges that count the number of days that count the cap base that on a separate counter that is not reset when recalls find you below the cap again. You can see that number in your rep audit view, [`<siteurl>/reputation`](/reputation).

Comment: Ah, no, that number reflects a recalculated number. The rep cap counter for the epic and legendary badges isn't publicly visible. See [Epic badge received too early?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/165634)